# Parse Android, pinAll() or pinAllInBackground() sometime didn't return anything

Tags: android, parse-platform

I query relational database from Parse server, then attempt to `pinALl()` / `pinAllInBackground()` to save queried data to local database. However, sometimes `pinAll`/`pinAllInBackground()` does not return anything (no exception, nothing). Then the app freezes.

Is anyone familiar with this problem regarding `pinAll()` and `pinAllInBackground`?

Comment: have you enabled local data store before initialize parse application?

Comment: Yes, I enabled local database before call initialize. As I said, SOMETIME pinAll/pinAllInBackground() did not work. Around 10% of time, it never return anything, just frozen.

Comment: Hey I'm having the same issue,
Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. It seems to be a bug. I solved unpinnng before pinning objects.

```html
//Say you've a list of obejcts called objectsCollection

ParseObject.unpinAll(objectsCollection);
ParseObject.pinAll(objectsCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

After long time of search ,try and error
Instead of using `pinAllInBackground(List<T> objects, SaveCallback callback)` I used `pinAllInBackground(String name, List<T> objects, SaveCallback callback)`

I don't know the problem but this solution satisfied me!

**Edit:**
I faced the problem again, and i got a solution, please check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925891/2294985